# Error compiling Ruby-1.9.3

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors

I am having problems compiling Ruby-1.9.3 on my linux box (Redhat).

I tried it using RVM and get the following errors:

```
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
compiling compile.c
compiling debug.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling vm.c
In file included from vm.c:27:
vm_method.c: In function ‘rb_gc_mark_unlinked_live_method_entries’:
vm_method.c:102: warning: unused variable ‘curr_ume’
vm_method.c:102: warning: unused variable ‘prev_ume’
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling thread.c
/tmp/ccsuOCyc.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccsuOCyc.s:243: Error: Incorrect register `%rax' used with `l' suffix
/tmp/ccsuOCyc.s:268: Error: Incorrect register `%rdx' used with `l' suffix
/tmp/ccsuOCyc.s:9562: Error: Incorrect register `%rax' used with `l' suffix
/tmp/ccsuOCyc.s:14547: Error: Incorrect register `%rax' used with `l' suffix
make: *** [thread.o] Error 1
```

I also tried to manually deploy ruby, but downloading the source tarballs and running configure/make etc and get the same error on compiling thread.c

Any ideas what the issue could be?  I've tried removing rvm/ruby and redoing multiple times to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated!

Adding more info:

$gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
```

$uname -a

```
Linux <machine name> 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:28:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

$cat Makefile

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
NULLCMD = :
RUNCMD = $(SHELL)
CHDIR = cd -P
exec = exec
NULL = /dev/null

#### Start of system configuration section. ####

srcdir = .
top_srcdir = $(srcdir)
hdrdir = $(srcdir)/include

CC = gcc
CPP = $(CC) -E
YACC = bison
PURIFY =
AUTOCONF = autoconf

MKFILES = Makefile
BASERUBY = echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
DOXYGEN = 

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
sbindir = ${exec_prefix}/sbin
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
datadir = ${datarootdir}
arch = x86_64-linux
sitearch = ${arch}
sitedir = ${rubylibprefix}/site_ruby
ruby_version = 1.9.1

TESTUI = console
TESTS =
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
DOCTARGETS = nodoc nodoc

EXTOUT = .ext
arch_hdrdir = $(EXTOUT)/include/$(arch)
VPATH = $(arch_hdrdir)/ruby:$(hdrdir)/ruby:$(srcdir)/enc:$(srcdir)/missing

empty =
OUTFLAG = -o $(empty)
COUTFLAG = -o $(empty)
ARCH_FLAG = 
CFLAGS = ${cflags}  -fPIC
cflags =  ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}
optflags = -O3
debugflags = -ggdb
warnflags = -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration
INCFLAGS = -I. -I$(arch_hdrdir) -I$(hdrdir) -I$(srcdir)
XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
CPPFLAGS =  $(DEFS) ${cppflags} $(INCFLAGS)
LDFLAGS =  $(CFLAGS) -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
EXTLDFLAGS = 
XLDFLAGS =  $(EXTLDFLAGS)
EXTLIBS = 
LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  $(EXTLIBS)
MISSING =  ${LIBOBJDIR}strlcpy.o ${LIBOBJDIR}strlcat.o ${LIBOBJDIR}setproctitle.o ${LIBOBJDIR}addr2line.o 
LDSHARED = $(CC) -shared
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME).so.$(MAJOR).$(MINOR) $(EXTLDFLAGS) $(ARCH_FLAG)
SOLIBS = $(LIBS)
MAINLIBS = 
ARCHMINIOBJS = dmydln.o
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS =  ascii.$(OBJEXT) us_ascii.$(OBJEXT) unicode.$(OBJEXT) utf_8.$(OBJEXT)
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS =  newline.$(OBJEXT)

RUBY_BASE_NAME=ruby
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION=1.9.3
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
RUBY_SO_NAME=$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
EXEEXT = 
PROGRAM=$(RUBY_INSTALL_NAME)$(EXEEXT)
RUBY = $(RUBY_INSTALL_NAME)
MINIRUBY = ./miniruby$(EXEEXT) -I$(srcdir)/lib -I. -I$(EXTOUT)/common\
    $(MINIRUBYOPT)
RUNRUBY = $(MINIRUBY) $(srcdir)/tool/runruby.rb --extout=$(EXTOUT) $(RUNRUBYOPT) -- $(RUN_OPTS)
XRUBY = $(RUNRUBY)
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL}
XRUBY_LIBDIR = 
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR = 
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR = 

DEFAULT_PRELUDES = $(YES_GEM_PRELUDE)

#### End of system configuration section. ####

MAJOR=  1
MINOR=  9
TEENY=  1

LIBRUBY_A     = lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME)-static.a
LIBRUBY_SO    = lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME).so.$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(TEENY)
LIBRUBY_ALIASES= lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME).so.$(MAJOR).$(MINOR) lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME).so
LIBRUBY       = $(LIBRUBY_SO)
LIBRUBYARG    = $(LIBRUBYARG_SHARED)
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R -Wl,$(libdir) -L$(libdir) -l$(RUBY_SO_NAME)-static
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R -Wl,$(libdir) -L$(libdir) -l$(RUBY_SO_NAME)

THREAD_MODEL  = pthread

PREP          = miniruby$(EXEEXT)
ARCHFILE      = 
SETUP         =
EXTSTATIC     = 
SET_LC_MESSAGES = env LC_MESSAGES=C

MAKEDIRS      = /bin/mkdir -p
CP            = cp
MV            = mv
RM            = rm -f
RMDIR         = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
RMDIRS        = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMALL         = rm -fr
NM            = nm
AR            = ar
ARFLAGS       = rcu
RANLIB        = ranlib
AS            = as
ASFLAGS       =  $(INCFLAGS)
IFCHANGE      = $(srcdir)/tool/ifchange
SET_LC_MESSAGES = env LC_MESSAGES=C
OBJDUMP       = objdump
OBJCOPY       = objcopy
VCS           = echo cannot
VCSUP         = $(VCS)

OBJEXT        = o
ASMEXT        = S
DLEXT         = so
MANTYPE       = doc
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 

INSTALLED_LIST= .installed.list

MKMAIN_CMD    = mkmain.sh

SRC_FILE      = $<

MESSAGE_BEGIN = @for line in
MESSAGE_END = ; do echo "$$line"; done

configure_args =  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--enable-shared' '--disable-install-doc' '--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/lib'
#### End of variables

all:

.DEFAULT: all

# Prevent GNU make v3 from overflowing arg limit on SysV.
.NOEXPORT:

miniruby$(EXEEXT):
        @-if test -f $@; then $(MV) -f $@ $@.old; $(RM) $@.old; fi
        $(ECHO) linking $@
        $(Q) $(PURIFY) $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(XLDFLAGS) $(MAINLIBS) $(NORMALMAINOBJ) $(MINIOBJS) $(COMMONOBJS) $(DMYEXT) $(LIBS) $(OUTFLAG)$@

$(PROGRAM):
        @$(RM) $@
        $(ECHO) linking $@
        $(Q) $(PURIFY) $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(XLDFLAGS) $(MAINLIBS) $(MAINOBJ) $(EXTOBJS) $(LIBRUBYARG) $(LIBS) $(OUTFLAG)$@

# We must `rm' the library each time this rule is invoked because "updating" a
# MAB library on Apple/NeXT (see --enable-fat-binary in configure) is not
# supported.
$(LIBRUBY_A):
        @$(RM) $@
        $(ECHO) linking static-library $@
        $(Q) $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(OBJS) $(DMYEXT)
        @-$(RANLIB) $@ 2> /dev/null || true

$(LIBRUBY_SO):
        @-$(PRE_LIBRUBY_UPDATE)
        $(ECHO) linking shared-library $@
        $(Q) $(LDSHARED) $(DLDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(DLDOBJS) $(SOLIBS) $(OUTFLAG)$@
        -$(Q) $(OBJCOPY) -w -L '$(SYMBOL_PREFIX)Init_*' -L '$(SYMBOL_PREFIX)*_threadptr_*' $@
        @-$(MINIRUBY) -e 'ARGV.each{|link| File.delete link if File.exist? link; \
                          File.symlink "$(LIBRUBY_SO)", link}' \
                $(LIBRUBY_ALIASES) || true

fake: $(arch)-fake.rb
$(arch)-fake.rb: config.status $(srcdir)/template/fake.rb.in
        @./config.status --file=$@:$(srcdir)/template/fake.rb.in
        @chmod +x $@

ruby_pc = ruby-1.9.pc
$(ruby_pc):
        @./config.status --file=$@:$(srcdir)/template/ruby.pc.in

install-cross: $(arch)-fake.rb $(RBCONFIG) rbconfig.rb $(arch_hdrdir)/ruby/config.h \
    $(LIBRUBY_A) $(LIBRUBY_SO) $(ARCHFILE)
    $(ECHO) installing cross-compiling stuff
    $(Q) $(MAKEDIRS) $(XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR)/$(arch) $(XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR)/$(arch)/ruby
    $(Q) sed '/^\$$:\.unshift/q' $(arch)-fake.rb > fake.rb
    $(Q) $(BASERUBY) -p \
    -e '~/^\s*CONFIG\["LDFLAGS"\]/ and' \
    -e '$$_[/(?=\s*"$$)/] = %q[ #{(CONFIG["LIBPATHFLAG"]%File.dirname(__FILE__)).strip}]' \
    rbconfig.rb > fake-rbconfig.rb
    $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) fake.rb $(XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR)/$(arch)/fake.rb
    $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) fake-rbconfig.rb $(XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR)/$(arch)/rbconfig.rb
    @$(RM) fake.rb fake-rbconfig.rb
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(arch_hdrdir)/ruby/config.h $(XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR)/$(arch)/ruby
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(top_srcdir)/include/ruby/win32.h $(XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR)/ruby
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(LIBRUBY) $(LIBRUBY_A) $(XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR)/$(arch)
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(LIBRUBY_SO) $(XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR)/$(arch)

Makefile:   $(srcdir)/Makefile.in $(srcdir)/enc/Makefile.in

$(MKFILES): config.status
        MAKE=$(MAKE) $(SHELL) ./config.status
        @{ \
            echo "all:; -@rm -f conftest.mk"; \
            echo "conftest.mk: .force; @echo AUTO_REMAKE"; \
            echo ".force:"; \
        } > conftest.mk || exit 1; \
        $(MAKE) -f conftest.mk | grep '^AUTO_REMAKE$$' >/dev/null 2>&1 || \
        { echo "Makefile updated, restart."; exit 1; }

uncommon.mk: $(srcdir)/common.mk
        sed 's/{\$$([^(){}]*)[^{}]*}//g' $< > $@

.PHONY: reconfig
reconfig-args = $(srcdir)/configure $(configure_args)
config.status-args = ./config.status --recheck
reconfig-exec-0 = exec 3>&1; exit `exec 4>&1; { "$$@" 3>&- 4>&-; echo $$? 1>&4; } | fgrep -v '(cached)' 1>&3`
reconfig-exec-1 = set -x; "$$@"

reconfig config.status: $(srcdir)/configure $(srcdir)/enc/Makefile.in
    @PWD= MINIRUBY="$(MINIRUBY)"; export MINIRUBY; \
    set $(SHELL) $($@-args); $(reconfig-exec-$(V))

$(srcdir)/configure: $(srcdir)/configure.in
    $(CHDIR) $(srcdir) && exec $(AUTOCONF)

incs: id.h

# Things which should be considered:
# * with gperf v.s. without gperf
# * committers may have various versions of gperf
# * ./configure v.s. ../ruby/configure
# * GNU make v.s. HP-UX make    # HP-UX make invokes the action if lex.c and keywords has same mtime.
# * svn checkout generate a file with mtime as current time
# * ext4 and XFS has a mtime with fractional part
lex.c: defs/keywords
    @\
    if cmp -s $(srcdir)/defs/lex.c.src $?; then \
      [ $(Q) ] && echo copying $@ || set -x; \
      $(CP) $(srcdir)/lex.c.blt $@; \
    else \
      [ $(Q) ] && echo generating $@ || set -x; \
      gperf -C -p -j1 -i 1 -g -o -t -N rb_reserved_word -k1,3,$$ $? > $@.tmp && \
      $(MV) $@.tmp $@ && \
      $(CP) $? $(srcdir)/defs/lex.c.src && \
      $(CP) $@ $(srcdir)/lex.c.blt; \
    fi

NAME2CTYPE_OPTIONS = -7 -c -j1 -i1 -t -C -P -T -H uniname2ctype_hash -Q uniname2ctype_pool -N uniname2ctype_p

enc/unicode/name2ctype.h: enc/unicode/name2ctype.kwd
    $(MAKEDIRS) $(@D)
    @set +e; \
    if cmp -s $(?:.kwd=.src) $?; then \
      set -x; \
      $(CP) $(?:.kwd=.h.blt) $@; \
    else \
      trap '$(RM) $@-1.h $@-2.h' 0 && \
      set -x; \
      sed '/^#ifdef USE_UNICODE_PROPERTIES/,/^#endif/d' $? | gperf $(NAME2CTYPE_OPTIONS) > $@-1.h && \
      gperf $(NAME2CTYPE_OPTIONS) < $? > $@-2.h && \
      diff -DUSE_UNICODE_PROPERTIES $@-1.h $@-2.h > $@.tmp || :; \
      $(MV) $@.tmp $@ && \
      $(CP) $? $(?:.kwd=.src) && \
      $(CP) $@ $(?:.kwd=.h.blt); \
    fi

.c.o:
    @$(ECHO) compiling $<
    $(Q) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(XCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(COUTFLAG)$@ -c $<

.s.o:
    @$(ECHO) assembling $<
    $(Q) $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.c.S:
    @$(ECHO) translating $<
    $(Q) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(XCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(COUTFLAG)$@ -S $<

.c.i:
    @$(ECHO) preprocessing $<
    $(Q) $(CPP) $(XCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(COUTFLAG)$@ -E $< > $@

clean-local::
    $(Q)$(RM) ext/extinit.c ext/extinit.$(OBJEXT) ext/ripper/y.output
    -$(Q)$(RM) $(pkgconfig_DATA)

distclean-local::
    $(Q)$(RM) ext/config.cache $(RBCONFIG) Doxyfile
    -$(Q)$(RM) run.gdb
    -$(Q)$(RM) $(INSTALLED_LIST) $(arch_hdrdir)/ruby/config.h
    -$(Q)$(RMDIRS) $(arch_hdrdir)/ruby 2> /dev/null || true

clean-ext distclean-ext realclean-ext::
    @cd ext 2>/dev/null || exit 0; set dummy `echo "${EXTS}" | tr , ' '`; shift; \
    test "$$#" = 0 && set .; \
    set dummy `\
        find "$$@" -name Makefile -print | sed 's:^\./::;s:/Makefile$$:~:' | sort | sed 's:~$$::'; \
    `; shift; \
    cd ..; \
    for dir do \
        echo $(@:-ext=)ing "$$dir"; \
        (cd "ext/$$dir" && exec $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) $(@:-ext=)) && \
        case "$@" in \
        *distclean-ext*|*realclean-ext*) \
        $(RMDIRS) "ext/$$dir" 2> /dev/null || true;; \
        esac; \
    done

distclean-ext realclean-ext::
    -$(Q)$(RMDIR) ext 2> /dev/null || true

clean-extout:
    -$(Q)$(RMDIRS) $(EXTOUT) 2> /dev/null || true

clean-enc distclean-enc realclean-enc:
    @test -f "$(ENC_MK)" || exit 0; \
    echo $(@:-enc=ing) encodings; \
    exec $(MAKE) -f $(ENC_MK) $(MFLAGS) $(@:-enc=)

clean-rdoc distclean-rdoc realclean-rdoc:
    @echo $(@:-rdoc=ing) rdoc
    $(Q)$(RMALL) $(RDOCOUT)
clean-capi distclean-capi realclean-capi:
    @echo $(@:-capi=ing) capi
    $(Q)$(RMALL) $(CAPIOUT)


ext/extinit.$(OBJEXT): ext/extinit.c $(SETUP)
    $(ECHO) compiling $@
    $(Q) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(XCFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(COUTFLAG)$@ -c ext/extinit.c

up::
    @$(CHDIR) "$(srcdir)" && LC_TIME=C exec $(VCSUP)

update-mspec:
    @$(CHDIR) $(srcdir); \
    if [ -d spec/mspec ]; then \
      cd spec/mspec; \
      echo updating mspec ...; \
      exec git pull; \
    else \
      echo retrieving mspec ...; \
      exec git clone $(MSPEC_GIT_URL) spec/mspec; \
    fi

update-rubyspec: update-mspec
    @$(CHDIR) $(srcdir); \
    if [ -d spec/rubyspec ]; then \
      cd spec/rubyspec; \
      echo updating rubyspec ...; \
      exec git pull; \
    else \
      echo retrieving rubyspec ...; \
      exec git clone $(RUBYSPEC_GIT_URL) spec/rubyspec; \
    fi

test-rubyspec-precheck:
    @if [ ! -d $(srcdir)/spec/rubyspec ]; then echo No rubyspec here.  make update-rubyspec first.; exit 1; fi

INSNS   = opt_sc.inc optinsn.inc optunifs.inc insns.inc insns_info.inc \
      vmtc.inc vm.inc

$(INSNS): $(srcdir)/insns.def vm_opts.h \
      $(srcdir)/defs/opt_operand.def $(srcdir)/defs/opt_insn_unif.def \
      $(srcdir)/tool/instruction.rb $(srcdir)/tool/insns2vm.rb
    $(ECHO) generating $@
    $(Q) $(BASERUBY) -Ks $(srcdir)/tool/insns2vm.rb $(INSNS2VMOPT) $@

distclean-local::; @$(RM) GNUmakefile uncommon.mk
```

rpm -qa | grep compat-libstdc

```
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61
compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-138
```

Comment: Are you on a 32 bit machine, or 64? Perhaps you need to have the environment variable ARCHFLAGS set or it is currently set incorrectly?

Comment: Don't have an exact answer for you, but Googling a few of the errors reported seem to point to 32/64bit issues relating to some of the required libs. Edit: or, what @DanierEvans said :-)

Comment: What compiler are you using? gcc? Or an LLVM backed one?

Comment: 64 bit kernal and 64 bit CPU.  Yes I also thought it was a 32/64 bit issue but nothing I tried to fix this seemed to work.

Comment: What happens when you do: $ sudo yum install ruby

Answer (score 1):

Some options for you...

If you have the RedHat Package Manager called "yum" try these:

```
$ sudo yum install ruby
$ sudo yum install ruby19
$ sudo yum install ruby19-devel
```

Try ruby-build:

```
https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build
```

Here are some places to look for leads... if you can post the results to these, more people here may be able to help you.

```
$ gcc -v
$ uname -a
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
$ cat ~/.rvmrc
$ cat Makefile
$ rpm -qa | grep compat-libstdc
```

What you're looking for is some difference between 32 bit vs. 64 bit. If you see items like "686" that's typically 32 bit; if you see items like "x64" that's typically 64 bit.

Are you using any compiler flags to choose 32 bit? For example in your Makefile:

```
CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32" CXXFLAGS="-m32"
```

If so, change them all to "-m64", then `make clean` and try again.

If your GCC is not current (4.7.2) I do suggest updating it, `make clean` and try again.

Comment: thanks. I've added the info above.  I tried to manually run Make with 64 bit flags, then 32 bit flags, but get errors with both... I'm not sure what else to try...

Comment: Thanks Alison, your new info looks good; the machine knows it's 64 bit, Ruby Makefile shows 64 bit. GCC is pretty far out of date, might want to try updating it. Can you try this? $ yum install ruby